# JavaFX проблемы с jar файлом

Tags: java, javafx

Здраствуйте, я написал FX приложение которое состоит из 3-ех окон. 
[image: После нажатия на Autorization открывается следуючее окно и.т.д.]

После нажатия на Autorization открывается следующее окно и.т.д.

```
 @FXML
public void Autentification(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {


    UserInform.AccauntName = name;
    UserInform.UserName = name;


    int intPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
    messages.PrintMessage("Authentication started\n", Out);

    ConnectionForUI.session.tryConnect(name, pass, host, intPort);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../ClientField.fxml"));
       Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
       Stage stage = new Stage();
       stage.setTitle("Client");
       stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
       stage.show();
```

Но когда я запускаю приложение с сформированого jar то после нажатия на Autorization следующее окно не открывается. Что я делаю не так?
В JavaFX я недавно поетому с таким никогда не сталкивался.

Exception:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибок нет? Окно следующее видимо? Может покажите код перехода на след. окно?

Comment: Ошибок нет, переход в следующее окно происходит уже в класе контролере,
в методе которий отвечает за кнопку AUTORIZATION. Cечас скину код

Comment: Идея следующая, при нажатии на авторизацию откривается новое окно.
В IDEA все работает, в jar-нике откривается только первое окно, при нажатии кнопки приходят данние и все, перехода в след окно не происходит

Comment: B main в методе start загружен FXML только авторизацийного окна

Comment: Ваше приложение не находит ресурс при автономном запуске и вываливается с исключением, поэтому до окна даже не доходит

Comment: я уже разобрался, надо было указать абсолютный путь

Answer (score 0):

До конца так и не разобрался в чем проблема, пути прописани относительно проекта, но помогло создать новый fxml и подключить его вместо старого, тогда все работает.